# Mysql UNIQUE INDEX on 3 fields when one field equals a value

Tags: mysql, alter-table, create-table, unique-index

I want to add a UNIQUE INDEX on 3 fields when one of the fields is True. ie equal to 1

UNIQUE INDEX pkg_box_delivered (package_id, box_id, delivered) WHERE delivered = 1;

I need a Alter statement and how add it to a Create Table statement.

Comment: To be clear, you want to enforce a constraint that no two records have the same values for `package_id` and `box_id` - but only where `delivered = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an index on *some* of the rows in a table - only on *all* the rows in a table regardless of value.

> I need a Alter statement and how add it to a Create Table statement

You use ALTER TABLE to change the definition of an existing table, while CREATE TABLE creates a table and it's fields, hence if the table exists already....

```
 ALTER TABLE yourtablename 
   ADD UNIQUE INDEX pkg_box_delivered (package_id, box_id, delivered);
```

or if it does not already exist....

```
 CREATE TABLE yourtablename (
         package_id INT NOT NULL,
         box_id INT NOT NULL,
         delivered BOOLEAN,
         ...
         UNIQUE INDEX pkg_box_delivered (package_id, box_id, delivered)
 );
```

Just as you can't selectively apply an index to some rows, you can't selectively apply the unique constraint. You'd need to add a trigger to enforce this.

Comment: Thank you but I already knew those statements. Problem is I only want those to be unique when delivered = 1 but I can't have trigger as I don't have access to when items are entered into the table.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I...want those to be unique when delivered = 1" If you mean that the combined valuie of the fields is only unique when delivered=1 then see the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: I understand I need a trigger now but I have no idea what it should look like. Also I already have data in my database which I can not delete.